# Redmine postgresql FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "redmine"

Tags: postgresql, authentication, redmine

Following the these instructions (using postgresql instead of mysql):
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Redmine_on_CentOS_installation_HOWTO

when run this command :

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

rake show an error message:

```
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "redmine"
```

??

Comment: SOLVED: simply add this line to your postgresql config file "pg_hba.conf":


hostnossl    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          password

Comment: You opened all databases to all users with a password. Change that to `hostnossl the_db redmine 127.0.0.1/32 password`

Answer (score 2):

It should not be necessary to modify pg_hba.conf for redmine.  First check that your database role is configured correctly:

```
    su - postgres
    psql -d redmine -U redmine -h localhost
    <password challenge>
```

If the password is accepted, then the next step is to confirm that you have `libopenssl-ruby` installed.

Comment: Great hack, the option "-h localhost" allowed me to run psql over SSH with no modification of pg_hba.conf, and using sql user instead of Linux user. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should have the postgres user name the same as your linux username
It's easier than modifying "pg_hba.conf" file

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`psql redmine redmine -h localhost`

The `-h localhost` part makes the difference.